# Where is the error in SQL query. error in using the aggregate function

Tags: mysql, group-by, having

I have to tables

TABLE MEDCOND

```
AGRDATEBEG  
            AGRISN  
                    PREMRUB 
2000-05-10    1      15
2000-05-11    1      20
2000-05-10    2      35
2001-05-10    3      55
2000-05-10    4      66
2003-05-17    1      10
2000-05-10    2      88
2000-05-19    1      99
2000-06-10    3      98
```

TABLE MEDREFUND

```
 AGRDATEBEG 
                AGRISN  
                        REFUNDSUMRUB    
    2000-05-10   1       2000
    2000-05-11   1       2000
    2000-05-10   2       500
    2001-05-10   3       1000
    2000-05-10   4       2000
    2003-05-17   1       40
    2000-05-10   2       500
    2000-05-19   1       700
    2000-06-10   3       800
```

I need to calculate the amount(REFUNDSUMRUB-PREMRUB) for each type (1, 2,3) for May 10, 2000

My SQL query and results

```
SELECT medcond.AGRISN, SUM(DISTINCT(REFUNDSUMRUB-PREMRUB)) as sum_ FROM medcond INNER JOIN medrefund ON medcond.AGRISN=medrefund.AGRISN WHERE medcond.AGRDATEBEG='2000-05-10' GROUP BY medcond.AGRISN;
```

RESULTS

```
AGRISN  sum_    
1      2695
2      877
4      1934
```

I don't understand where the number 2695 for type 1 came from, it must be 1985, the rest of the results are correct. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your join matches all of the data from table *MEDREFUND* regardless of the date (check my fiddle)

To calculate the total for each type, use CTEs to get total per table, then perform the soustraction. :

```
WITH refund_sum as (
  select AGRISN, sum(REFUNDSUMRUB) as REFUNDSUMRUB
  from medrefund
  WHERE AGRDATEBEG='2000-05-10'
  group by AGRISN
),
prem_sum as (
  select AGRISN, sum(PREMRUB) as PREMRUB
  from medcond
  WHERE AGRDATEBEG='2000-05-10'
  group by AGRISN
)
select r.AGRISN, REFUNDSUMRUB - PREMRUB as sum_
from refund_sum r
inner join prem_sum m on m.AGRISN = r.AGRISN
```

Result :

```
AGRISN  SUM
1       1985
2       877
4       1934
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/OER88NUT)

Comment: `r` and `m` are aliases, we use them to give a table, or a column in a table, a temporary name, so `r.AGRISN` is the same as `refund_sum.AGRISN`